# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to rename: Input/output error

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I apply tensorflow eager mode to train a classifier, I met the following error.

```
Steps 151, Train loss is 0.00039766659028828144, learning_rate is 0.009999999776482582
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Tensorflow_Experiments/train_alexnet.py", line 1354, in <module>
```

The error occurs after several iterations, as shown above. But the iteration number is different for successional executions.

```
  File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\eager\python\saver.py", line 156, in save
    None, file_prefix, write_meta_graph=False, global_step=global_step)
  File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1451, in save
    save_relative_paths=self._save_relative_paths)
  File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 237, in update_checkpoint_state_internal
    text_format.MessageToString(ckpt))
  File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 436, in atomic_write_string_to_file
    rename(temp_pathname, filename, overwrite)
  File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 415, in rename
    compat.as_bytes(oldname), compat.as_bytes(newname), overwrite, status)
  File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to rename: ./hundred_models\model1\checkpoint.tmpc4b15b8c1e2d48b394f810909a0838b6 to: ./hundred_models\model1\checkpoint : \udcbeܾ\udcf8\udcb7\udcc3\udcceʡ\udca3
; Input/output error
```

Comment: Can you check this Stack Overflow Question and let us know if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is way to late, but [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4177%5D) is what fixed it for me.

Check whether you have a similarly named folder or in my code a csv logger interfered with the creation of the checkpoint.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29378536)

Comment: checking for similarly named folders and the csv logger is what fixed it for me. I included the information that helped me solve the problem.

Comment: I have a similar error when saving the checkpoint model. Like what @erisch said, just renaming the targeted folder solves the issue.